# reCaptcha always return a bool(false)

Tags: php, recaptcha

I having a issue with my recaptcha. The problem is that it always returns false meaning it says the captcha failed. even when the right word is typed in.
. i think its problem in ipv6 . can its possible i send recaptcha response through ipv4 or gethostbyname($host) like smtp php mailer

this is code

```
   if (isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])) {    
$secret = '6LdGuRGJefNf_yYwlpVl1uEkTo7';
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

$captcha = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
$rsp = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=$secret&response=$captcha&remoteip=$ip");
var_dump($rsp);
$validation = json_decode($rsp, TRUE);
var_dump($validation);
if ($validation['success'] !== true) {
    $errors[] = 'CAPTCHA failed. Please try again.';
    }
}
```

Comment: If that's your actual secret key it's probably not a good idea to share it

Comment: Use this instead of trying to roll your own https://github.com/google/recaptcha